# How to Remove New Line Only Where After The New Line There Is No Character

Tags: flutter, dart

As stated in the title. for example:

> Note: please check carefully the value of these three variables

```
String textA = 'this text contains many new line\n\n\n\nbut this ok, because there is a character after the new line';
String textB = 'I want remove all new Line because no character after new Line\n\n\n\n';
String textC = '\n\n\n\nAnd this still Ok, I dont want to remove all the new lines in front';
```

from that variable we can try print for see the result

textA will be

```
this text contains many new line
// new Line
// new Line
// new Line
but this ok, because there is a character after the new line
```

textB will be

```
I want remove all new Line because no character after new Line
// new Line    - I want delete this new Line
// new Line    - I want delete this new Line
// new Line    - I want delete this new Line
```

textC will be

```
// new Line
// new Line
// new Line
And this still Ok, I dont want to remove all the new lines in front
```

you know we cant input \n (space form Enter your keyboard) to text field, when \n position in the last String, \n should be removed
. How to solve this problem in dart or flutter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this regex `r'[\s\S]*\S'`.

```dart
void main() {
  final regex = RegExp(r'[\s\S]*\S');

  String textA =
      'this text contains many new line\n\n\n\nbut this ok, because there is a character after the new line';
  String textB =
      'I want remove all new Line because no character after new Line\n\n\n\n';
  String textC =
      '\n\n\n\n\nAnd this still Ok, I dont want to remove all the new lines in front';

  print('-');
  print(regex.firstMatch(textA)?.group(0));
  print('-');
  print(regex.firstMatch(textB)?.group(0));
  print('-');
  print(regex.firstMatch(textC)?.group(0));
  print('-');
}
```

[image]

**Update**: *you can try `str.trimRight()` too. I think it is simple and* works the same.

```dart
final trimmed = '\nDart\n\n is fun\n\n'.trimRight();
print('-');
print(trimmed);
print('-');
// result
-

Dart


 is fun
-
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure in what kind of code you're trying to do this but the approach would be like this:

if string contains '\n'
check if string ends with '\n' if not then you replace \n with ''.

Answer (score 0):

String does have one function trim() it will trim the space before and after the text.

```
   Text(
              'I want remove all new Line because no character after new Line\n\n\n\n'.trim(),
            )
```

Answer (score -1):

You can replace \n to '' using this

var string = string.replaceAll('\n', '');

Comment: have you seen the text on variable textA and textC?
using your suggestion will remove all new-line without condition what I want